# MongoDB: How to define a dynamic entity in my own domain class?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dynamic

New to MongoDB. Set up a C# web project in VS 2013.

Need to insert data as document into MongoDB. The number of `Key-Value` pair every time could be different.

For example,  
 
  `document 1: Id is "1"`, data is one pair key-value: `"order":"shoes"`  
  `document 2: Id is "2"`, data is a 3-pair key-value: `"order":"shoes", "package":"big", "country":"Norway"`

In this "[Getting Started](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/#getting-started-with-csharp-driver)" says because it is so much easier to work with your own domain classes this quick-start will assume that you are going to do that. suggests make our own class like:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then use it like:

```
var entity = new Entity { Name = "Tom" };
...
entity.Name = "Dick";
collection.Save(entity);
```

Well, it defeats the idea of no-fixed columns, right?

So, I guess `BsonDocument` is the the model to use and is there any good samples for beginners?

Answer (score 1):

I'm amazed how often this topic comes up... Essentially, this is more of a 'statically typed language limitation' than a MongoDB issue:

Schemaless doesn't mean you don't have any schema per se, it basically means you don't have to tell the database *up front* what you're going to store. *It's basically "code first"* - the code just writes to the database like it would to RAM, with all the flexibility involved.

Of course, the typical application will have some sort of reoccurring data structure, some classes, some object-oriented paradigm in one way or another. That is also true for the indexes: indexes are (usually) 'static' in the sense that you *do* have to tell mongodb about which field to index up front.

However, there is also the use case where you don't know what to store. If your data is really that unforeseeable, it makes sense to think "code first": what would you do in C#? Would you use the `BsonDocument`? Probably not. Maybe an embedded `Dictionary` does the trick, e.g.

```
public class Product {
    public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes {get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

This solution can also work with [multikeys to simulate a large number of indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups) to make queries on the attributes reasonably fast (though the lack of static typing makes range queries tricky). See

It really depends on your needs. If you want to have **nested objects and static typing**, things get a lot more complicated than this. Then again, the consumer of such a data structure (i.e. the frontend or client application) often needs to make assumptions that make it easy to digest this information, so it's often not possible to make this type safe anyway.

Other options include indeed using the `BsonDocument`, which I find too invasive in the sense that you make your business models depend on the database driver implementation; or using a common base class like `ProductAttributes` that can be extended by classes such as `ProductAttributesShoes`, etc. This question really revolves around the whole system design - do you know the properties at compile time? Do you have dropdowns for the property values in your frontend? Where do they come from?

If you want something reusable and flexible, you could simply use a JSON library, serialize the object to string and store that to the database. In any case, the interaction with such objects will be ugly from the C# side because they're not statically typed.